# Закончился пробный период в mamp pro, но я забыл скачать бд, что делать? Можно ли как то взломать mamp или скачать бд?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

В MAMP PRO, есть бесплатный период который составляет 14 дней, он истёк и теперь ни бд ни localhost не работает, можно ли крашнуть(взломать) mamp pro, или хотя бы получить sql файл базы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: крякать незаконно. попробуйте купить лицензию

Comment: Peter Kolosov, в рф тоже не законно покупать лицензию

Answer (score 0):

Отделяете папку `data` от текущего MySQL 5.7.39, закидываете в свой MYSQL сервер той-же версии или минор версии 5.7.XX

https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7019203

Cбрасываете права ROOT через безопасный режим MySQL

https://dbtut.com/index.php/2018/08/08/connect-to-mysql-server-without-password-in-safe-mode/

Перезагружаете БД и заходите под root пользователем в свою БД.

Желательно экспортировать базу через mysqldump с польным отвязываенм от пользователей, отключаетесь от чужой data на новую и просто инпортируете БД.